# SQL Server efficiently filter rows where times are not near another table's times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables and I'm looking for the rows in one table where a time column is *not* near any of the values in another table's time column. (Near is defined as within a minute).

Here's a code sample:

```
create table temp1
(
    id int identity primary key,
    value datetime not null 
)
GO

create index ix_temp1 on temp1(value, id);
GO

set nocount on
insert temp1 (value) values (DATEADD(second, rand() * 1000000, '20100101'))
GO 15000
```

table temp2 is set up identical:

```
create table temp2
(
    id int identity primary key,
    value datetime not null 
)
GO

create index ix_temp2 on temp2(value, id);
GO

set nocount on
insert temp2 (value) values (DATEADD(second, rand() * 1000000, '20100101'))
GO 15000
```

And here's my first crack at it (which is very inefficient)

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value
FROM temp1 t1
LEFT JOIN temp2 t2
    ON t1.value between DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t2.value) and DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t2.value)
WHERE t2.value is null
```

I'm looking for ways to do this more efficiently. All solutions will be considered (new indexes, SSIS solution, CLR solutions, temp tables, cursors etc...)

Comment: What does your execution plan look like?

Comment: Probably same as yours (if you try out the sample) I see parallelism.  The join is an loops join giving 50 million rows which gets filtered down to about 2500 rows. I can upload it somewhere if you really need to see more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LEFT JOIN/IS NULL isn't as efficient on SQL Server as NOT IN or NOT EXISTS when columns are not nullable - see [this link for details](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

That said, this:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.value
  FROM temp1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM temp2 t2
                   WHERE t2.value BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t1.value)  
                                      AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t1.value))
```

...still has a problem in that function use (IE: DATEADD) renders the index useless.  You're altering the data of the column (temporarily, without writing it back to the table) while the index is on the original value.

I'm at a loss for options if you want the precision.  Otherwise, if you alter the datetime before it's inserted into the temp table then you gain:

1. ability to straight compare:  `t1.value = t2.value`
2. ability to use the index, assuming optimizer believes it can be of use

Comment: unfortunately the precision is needed.

Comment: @Michael J Swart: I figured as much, but thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: But I may be able to weed out many by calculating the time to the minute. Times that are part of the same minute are within a minute of eachother. This would give a smaller list to work with (which may help a bit)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it pretty quick:

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.value
FROM 
(
   SELECT t1.id, 
          t1.value, 
          (SELECT MIN(temp2.value) FROM temp2 WHERE temp2.value >= t1.value) as theNext, 
          (SELECT MAX(temp2.value) FROM temp2 WHERE temp2.value <= t1.value) as thePrev
   FROM temp1 t1
) t 
WHERE DATEDIFF(second, t.value, t.theNext) > 60 
  AND DATEDIFF(second, t.thePrev, t.value) > 60
```

and it doesn't require any restructure of your tables.

Make sure and use seconds for the comparison, since minutes will get rounded. This runs in less than a second on my machine using your specifications for table creation.

EDIT: Added <= and >= to theNext and thePrev calculations. This prevents a false positive where temp1.value is equal to temp2.value.

Comment: It doesn't return the same results. On my test data 2388 vs 6126 rows.

Comment: This doesn't return the same result set as the original query when I tried it on my machine, using the OPs tables.

Comment: @Martin - if there's that big a difference, you probably caught it before I updated it to use seconds instead of minutes. Minutes get rounded and screw with the calculation. Also edited my answer to fix the smaller number of false matches.

Comment: @md5sum - Yes that returns the same number of rows now and seems quite fast as well (though I think mine might have the edge!). (+1)

Comment: @Martin - I dunno... :-P Both seem to run real close to ~300ms on my machine for 2400 rows returned... I'm not too picky past that point usually.

Comment: I was basing my claim on the logical reads count with `set statistics io on` but I guess it's entirely possible for different data distributions the results may be different.

Comment: You bet, this solution is also amazing. I'm a lucky question asker, I have two great answers to pick from. But I have to have some way to break ties and so logical reads is the tiebreaker for me too. I'm afraid Martin Smith's answer has the edge.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer Rewritten**

For your original query changing the Join condition from

```
LEFT JOIN temp2 t2
 ON t1.value BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t2.value) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t2.value)
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN temp2 t2
 ON t2.value BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t1.value) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t1.value)
```

Makes a huge difference.

In both it has a scan on temp1 as the outer input to the nested loops
iterator. However for the first one the condition on temp2 is not sargable so it needs to do a scan
on the whole of temp2 *for each row* in temp1. For the second version it can do a much more reasonable
range seek on the index to retrieve the matching row(s).

However the `Not Exists` solution as per [@OMG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719249/sql-server-efficiently-filter-rows-where-times-are-not-near-another-tables-times/3719541#3719541) is [more efficient in SQL Server](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

### Execution Plans:

(Ignore the "Cost Relative to the Batch" for the second one - The estimated rows are way off actual so this figure is misleading)

[ExecutionPlans http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/457/executionplans.jpg](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/457/executionplans.jpg)

Comment: @Michael - I had discounted the simple `NOT EXISTS` solution from @OMG Ponies answer due to the commentary that went with it but I've now tested it and found that is better than mine as it saves a scan on `temp1`!

Comment: ... Also your original query can be massively improved by changing the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN temp2 t2 ON t2.value BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, t1.value) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, t1.value)`. Though it is still beaten by the others.

Answer (score 0):

my first suggestion is to give this to one of the developers and have them code up an algorithm in C or C#

otherwise here is an idea. take the original data in the table and create new rows for plus and minus one minute. might be a lot of data if you're using seconds. then compare it with the data from the second table like you were doing

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with an issue similar to this by converting the DateTime value to the integer number of minutes since 1/1/2000--and writing that value into a column in my database table. So (in your case) the table would look like this:

```
create table temp2
(
    id int identity primary key,
    timeValue int not null
)
```

To compare with this table, just convert your comparison value to the integer number of minutes (I use a user-defined function for this) and compare.

```
DECLARE @newTime int;
SET @newTime = dbo.fnGetComparisonTime(@DateTimeValue)
```

Then retrieve your data:

```
SELECT id, timeValue 
FROM temp2
WHERE timeValue NOT BETWEEN (@newTime - 1) AND @newTime;
```

And the convert time to integer minutes function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetComparisonTime
    (
        @DateTimeValue datetime
    )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declarations
    DECLARE @Output int
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime

    SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
    SET @Output = DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @ReportDateTime)    

    -- And we're done!
    RETURN @Output

END
```

You can play around with the SELECT statement, of course, to get the results you want. Converting DateTime values to minutes is WAY faster than handling this with dates directly.

You might ask--is there a Y2K kind of problem with this? (You will, after all, run out of minutes at 31^2 - 1 minutes.) Yes--in about 7000 years. Be sure to document your code carefully....

Comment: I'm personally really not fond of this type of solution. I understand that it will perfectly well work, but it requires a lot more understanding of the system for a new developer or contractor to begin working on your system, and it reduces maintainability within the codebase. There are plenty of better, more understandable, and easily maintained methods to perform this same task. On top of all that, you still have to build the same complexity of base query implementing this new methodology in order to gather the same data. You're simply changing the comparison type.

Answer (score -1):

This is really fast..

;WITH Time_CTE (ID,Table1_Time,Table2_Time)
AS
(
SELECT t1.id, t1.value AS Table1_Time, t2.value AS Table2_Time
FROM temp1 t1
INNER JOIN temp2 t2 ON YEAR(t1.value) = YEAR(t2.value)
                        AND MONTH(t1.value) = MONTH(t2.value)
                        AND DAY(t1.value) = DAY(t2.value)
)

SELECT TCTE.id, TCTE.Table1_Time
FROM Time_CTE TCTE
WHERE DATEDIFF(ss,Table1_Time,Table2_Time) < 61
OR DATEDIFF(ss,Table2_Time,Table1_Time) < 61

Comment: Think there must be an error in it (I cancelled execution after 32 seconds by which time it had output 870,000 rows)

Comment: I'm sorry... this actually runs slower than the solution that the OP posted... and after 2:52 on my machine it finally threw a System.OutOfMemoryException... with 16777216 rows...